# Select % in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, join, select, subquery

Hi I am have trouble with selecting a % of records. I have my SQL that works and selects everything

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT  
        Distinct(LPEL_PRO_PROPREF)....
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by "Value" Order By "Value" 
        desc) as "row_num",
        lpel_fat_code as "Lot",
        DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,25000) as "Random Sequence"
           
FROM table1
JOIN table2 on table.value = table2.value
JOIN table3 on table2.value = table3.value

Where lpel_fat_code LIKE '%LOTS%)
```

What I need is to select 10% of LOTS1, 10% of LOTS2 etc. The numbers for each Lot vary and there are 6 lots. I am thinking that I may need to do some kind of join but I am not sure. Also, I only have access to select data, I cannot create any new tables or views. Once written, this data would be extracted in SSRS.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Distinct` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. `SELECT DISTINCT` will give you distinct _rows_.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output. It is not clear what is the issue and what output you expect

Comment: I have used distinct and I only want the values in LPEL_PRO_PROPREF to appear once, if I have it in, it will appear for various historic records. The table I want has 27 columns of which 1 is titled LOT (lpel_fat_code). The values in here vary from LOTS1 to LOTS6 (as well as some others). There are 2220 record with a value of LOTS1, I would like to return a random 222 records, LOTS2 has 576, I would like to return 57 (give or take 1) but in the same table.

Lot         Contractor
LOTS2 Contractor Name
LOTS3 Contractor Name